# GitHub action failed at npm ci

Tags: github, github-actions

`npm ci` passes locally, but fails when running as part of GitHub action to build and deploy to Firebase hosting. Project is Angular 13.

The error is: `npm ERR! The 'npm ci' command can only install with an existing package-lock.json`

[image]

This is the yaml config file:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MY_WEBSITE }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: my-website
```

Comment: did you try the suggestion point from the error?. I think you have `package-lock.json` in your `.gitignore` file excluded

Comment: @Sysix `package-lock.json` is not in `.gitignore` and it is showing in the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow "[Super fast npm install on Github Actions
Super fast npm install on Github Actions](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/)" by [**De Voorhoede**](https://twitter.com/devoorhoede):

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: Cache dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: npm-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: npm-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: cd my-site && npm ci --ignore-scripts
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^

      # run npm test, build, lint, etc.
```

That way, `package-lock.json` should be properly generated.

That should work if you are in the right folder, since the [OP matchifang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5051564/matchifang) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483630/github-action-failed-at-npm-ci/70485135?noredirect=1#comment124744420_70485135):

> I found out I was in the wrong directory.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me this error in the 'Install Dependencies step': `npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/my-website/my-website/package.json'` Do I need to change anything in that step?

Comment: Check if, when checked out, your repository does have a `package.json` file.

Comment: I read through the logs, but it's not obvious to me where I can find the files that's been checked out.. can you point me to how I can find it?

Comment: @mat After the checkout step, I would simply execute a sh step with the command `find .`, in order to list all files from the current folder

Comment: I found out I was in the wrong directory. Thank you! :D

Comment: @matchifang OK. I have edited the answer to include your finding.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. The issue was that I was in the wrong directory and had to add 'cd my-site && ' then the npm ci commands

Answer (score -2):

try using yarn instead of npm it worked on me.

Comment: though yarn does not have ci command as far as I know, I used 'yarn install'